# Resolving an alias to a remote server

Tags: unix, ftp, aix

I have what I think is called an IP alias, which is used to access a Windows file server from a Unix server. The path on Unix looks something like:

```
/folder/file.txt
```

which is somehow resolved as:

```
\\server\folder\file.txt
```

This is used within an ftp command from a SAS program running on Unix. I know very little about Unix, but I believe the alias is configured on Unix itself (not by the SAS server). As a normal (non-root) user, is there a way of looking up this alias and seeing the IP address it refers to? Or even better, a list of aliases and their IP addresses?

Perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology? My Google searches have turned up command aliases, but otherwise I've found very little helpful information.

Comment: Questions about Unix and Linux are equally on topic here and should not be migrated away. However, if you don't get an answer within, say a few days, feel free to have it migrated there by flagging again. Cheers

Comment: @slhck - Thanks. Didn't want to open a second, identical question on another site. The suggestion above is reasonable.

Comment: Now reposted on [unix.se]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76130/resolving-an-alias-to-a-remote-server

Answer (score 1):

Unix lets you mount filesystems, including remote filesystems, under directories on your system. This is similar to the way you can attach a remote filesystem as a drive on your windows machine, e.g. creating a Z: that refers to `\\server\folder`. Instead of using drive letters, we have directories that refer to filesystems. So `/folder` could be a remote mount of a shared folder on the Windows file server, i.e. `\\server\folder`. Run the `mount` command, it will show you currently mounted filesystems, including remote ones. Also, do `cat /etc/fstab` and look for a line like

```
//192.168.0.244/Public  /networkstorage cifs    rw,user,noauto,guest  0 0
```

where `//192.168.0.244/Public` stands for `\\192.168.0.244\Public` and `/networkstorage` is the "mountpoint", the place in the Unix filesystem where the remote filesystem is attached.

IP aliases are something entirely different. Command aliases are not what you want either.

Comment: `mount` gave me a list, but it does not include the mounts that I use in the SAS program. I don't have access to /etc/fstab. Clearly I'll need to work this out with the admins. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If the alias is defined on the Unix system, it should be in `/etc/hosts`. 
Try using `grep` to search for the server name in `/etc/hosts`,
or just browse the whole file to see all aliases that are defined there.

Comment: I actually tried that, but I thought I must have been mistaken because I couldn't find the alias there. (I used vi to search for "folder" and got nothin')

Comment: Oops; I misread your question.  I thought you were using an alias for the server name when you accessed the file on the server.  If the server’s `folder` directory is showing up on the Unix system as `/folder`, then the Unix system probably has it mounted (as a remote file system).  Type `mount` (or `/etc/mount`, if you get a “not found” error) and see whether you see server listed.